# How to end a while loop properly?

Tags: python

I want to create a program that asks a user for sentences that then combine to create a story that is displayed to the user. The user decides how many sentences he or she wishes to write.

This is probably a dumb question with a simple answer, but with the code below a `q` or `Q` is always added to the end of the story when I don't want the end command to be included. How can I eliminate this `q` from the printed story so that the user only gets his or her story returned to them.

Thank you for any help.

```
sent = ""
story = ""
while sent != 'q' and sent != 'Q':

    sent = input("Enter the sentence(Enter 'q' to quit): ")
    story += sent


print(story)
```

Comment: you should use raw_input

Comment: @self what if he's using python 3?

Comment: You might want to add a line break or a space. The last word of the previous line is together with the next line :)

Answer (score 2):

You should check after input, if the look should end or not. If so you can exit using `break`

```
story = ""
while True
    sentence = input("Enter the sentence(Enter 'q' to quit): ")
    if sentence.lower() != 'q':
        story += sent
    else:
        break

print(story)
```

Comment: shorter: `if sentence.lower() != "q":`

Answer (score 1):

The extra 'q' gets inserted because you are storing the character 'q' in variable sent. Perform story+=sent before the input statement instead.

```
sent = ""
story = ""
while sent.lower() != 'q':
    story += sent
    sent = input("Enter the sentence(Enter 'q' to quit): ")
print(story)
```